# SVG text element is not visible

Tags: html, svg

Basically I want to map `SVG` canvas to -1..1 and print some text on the canvas.

The simple example **without** mapping requested, is:

```css
  <style>
   .text {font: 14pt sans-serif; fill: red;}
  </style>
```

```html
<svg class="text" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<text x="0" y="14pt">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

What i want is **this** code to display a text:

```css
  <style>
   .text {font: 14pt sans-serif; fill: red;}
  </style>
```

```html
<svg class="text" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<text x="0" y="0">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

As I had understand from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text), the center of the canvas will be at 0,0. I expect the text string to be printed at the center(above the zero point actually). I am definitely missing something with this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Your font is too big: 14pt vs the size of the svg canvas: width:2, height:2

Comment: @enxaneta The svg canvas is just _some_ units. I thought the font will scale. Anyway, care to make your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've commented: your font is too big: 14pt vs the size of the svg canvas: width:2, height:2. In order to understand what happens I've centred the svg canvas in the middle of the window (little square with a silver border) and added `overflow:visible;` so that you can see the text.

```css
.text {font: 14pt sans-serif; fill: red;}
svg{
border:1px solid silver;
width:25px;
height:25px;
display:block;
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<svg class="text" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<text x="0" y="0">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

The solution to your problem is to set a bigger viewBox and a smaller font size. You may be tempted to use a very small font size for the viewBox you have (-1 -1 2 2). Please read this article: [The Limits of Numbers in SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html)

Answer (score -1):

Set the position of the text to the center of the element:

1. You can use, x="50%" y ="50%".
2. Use the text-anchor property to center the text horizontally with the value middle.
   Here is a simple demo:

```html
<svg width="200" height="100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">TEXT</text>    
</svg>
```